# Copying Maven Dependency into Project Structure

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I've been stuck on one specific Maven task for a while now, and I haven't been able to find anything specific to it.

I'm trying to host a few files as a dependency in my internal Maven repository (Sonatype Nexus). The catch is, I need it to **be placed into a specific folder in the project structure**.

In other words, I need dependency A to be placed into /src/WebContent/VAADIN/themes/${project.name}/

Looking over [this helpful page from the Maven website](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html) I was able to copy the dependency onto the hard disk in the exact location that I wanted, but it's not actually part of the project itself, so other classes have no idea it's there. Here's the exact code, though it's mostly a copy from the linked page:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>com.dsa.mobi</groupId>
                        <artifactId>DSAStyles</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/${project.name}/</outputDirectory>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, even if it's just a link to some documentation that might clear this up -- I looked over all of the XML documentation for Maven, which is confusing to find and more confusing to navigate, but I have yet to find a panacea for this >.>

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Here's an image of the folder structure in Eclipse's Project Explorer:
[image: Project Structure]

As you can see, only addons.scss and fisafetyapp.scss show up in this folder, whereas I'm trying to get Maven/the dependency to plug files into this exact location.

On disk, the dependency is being placed in this folder correctly, ie C:/myuser/fisafetyapp/src/main/webcontent/vaadin/themes/fisafetyapp/. However, it's not showing up in the Project Explorer, which keeps the other files from seeing it as the location is highly specific.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: `project.build.outputDirectory`?

Comment: Hey kamaci,

I tried project.build.outputDirectory for funsies, but that's going to /target/etcetcetc, which makes sense for 'output', but the issue I'm trying to resolve is getting it into the proper folder in the project *source* structure, IE what you would see when looking at the Project Explorer in Eclipse

Comment: Is it [`<dependency>/<scope>provided`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies) what you're looking for?

Comment: Hey Gerold, thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately a no-go. This is less about <scope> as it is about trying to get the dependency to place its files in a specific location within the project. The framework I'm using, Vaadin, expects specific files in specific locations, and I'm trying to deliver those files in a maven-supported solution so as to be able to change them and just update the repository and push it out to all codebases that way.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is right, not forget in your pom declaration to dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.dsa.mobi</groupId>
   <artifactId>DSAStyles</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: I appreciate the response! Unfortunately, after adding the <dependency> in before the <build>, nothing changed - it's still copying to the C:\path\that\I\gave\it, but it only does that on disk and does not have any association with the project itself. The goal is to have it install into a directory in the project, not just on disk somewhere [For clarity, the path on disk is 'in the project' but Eclipse doesn't know the file exists whatsoever so it's not actually visible to the Project]

Comment: @user3003246 What do you exactly mean by „_does not have any association with the project itself_“? If a library is declared as a dependency, as _q_m_c_ shows it, Maven resolves the dependency from the local (or a remote) repository and such its content can be used by the project. That _is_ an _association_.

Comment: I've edited the original post to contain an image and a bit more explanation -- I hope that clears it up a little bit. Essentially the files exist on disk, but aren't being placed in the Project Explorer directory setup and in such a way, the CSS @import statements can't find them. [[I realize the files are packed as a JAR at the moment, I figure dismantling the JAR will be step 2 once I get them placed correctly]]

Answer (score 0):

Copy the dependency with the `maven-dependency-plugin` into the `src/main/resources` folder in `generate-resources` phase *(don't forget to add these files to source control ignore list)*. Then the resources plugin will automatically copy it into the `target/classes` folder and it will be also automatically added to your end artifact.